# Can valigrind memcheck be used with CGo?

Tags: go, valgrind

we have an application that is mostly Go (1.17) that makes a lot of calls through CGo (GCC 7.5) to CUDA on an ARM processor. We occasionally see panics that look like something has done bad things to the heap in the C side. I tried running the whole application under valgrind, but I get too many messages like

```
==14869== Thread 1:
==14869== Invalid read of size 8
==14869==    at 0x4783AC: runtime.startm (proc.go:2508)
==14869==    by 0x47890B: runtime.wakep (proc.go:2584)
==14869==    by 0x47CF8F: runtime.newproc.func1 (proc.go:4261)
==14869==    by 0x4A476B: runtime.systemstack (asm_arm64.s:230)
==14869==    by 0x4A465F: runtime.mstart (asm_arm64.s:117)
==14869==  Address 0x1fff0001a8 is on thread 1's stack
==14869==  8 bytes below stack pointer
```

to see anything useful. I am assuming these are false positives, and the Go runtime is not in fact riddled with undefined behaviour. I can't see a flag to suppress that check. Have I missed it? Is there some other way to investigate this problem? I could write test harnesses in C++ but that will change the use pattern which I suspect is key to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I build the cgo software to an executable with

```
  go build
```

which produces an executable by the name of the directory you are in. Let's say it's call "mycgoprog"
I then run valgrind against it with this command:

```
G_SLICE=always-malloc G_DEBUG=gc-friendly  valgrind -v --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --num-callers=40 --log-file=valgrind.log ./mycgoprog
```

The valgrind.log then contains the all the indiscretions detected by valgrind in the linked c code.